# Java script for tracking Keywords used by Visitor which Leads to my website

Tags: javascript

I really want a script which fill my needs for knowing the keywords which were used by the visitor ... thanks in advance and please if you can help me with Visitor page tracking as well it would be icing on top :)..

Visitor Page tracking means to track the page or Log the information about the pages which visitor hits or landed in

Answer (score 2):

Try signing up for Google Analytics: http://www.google.com/analytics/

Comment: yes i forgot to mention i dont want to use google analytics as i need rapid result because of the condition of my application... Google Analytics is restricting me to first get data from them and then Export to CSV or whatever and then finally use it for my application :S and thats bad

Answer (score 1):

This will work for Google at least (non-instant search), and probably other search engines:

```
searchTerms = document.referrer.match(/[?&]q=(.*?)[&$]/);
searchTerms = searchTerms && decodeURIComponent(searchTerms[1]);
```

Comment: this is true for now, in short google will activate https for every searchoperation, than no searchquery parameter will submitted at all.

Comment: Sorry, if that doesn't make sense then you're better off subscribing to Analytics or some other service.

Answer (score 0):

I second Google Analytics.  You can also check out http://Piwik.org, an open-sourced alternative.

-- EDIT --
With respect to your comment. If you're using PHP you might want to check out `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`.  As that will help you begin to decode the search parameters included in the query string.

Comment: yah :S checked that 2.. they all behave in the same way i dont really want to log on other software and export data manually from that and then use it for my application :S im basically developing a chat application which is used by agents who make sales and i need fast results for that as soon as person login to our website i need  to know what he have searched for in order to get over here